# Run further steps against a string only if re.sub() matches

Tags: python, regex, performance

I have a series of strings. Some of them match a particular regular expression. If (and only if) they do, I want to do a substitution based on that regular expression and then some further processing as well.

That can naively be written as:

```
for string in stringlist:
  if re.search(r'^A \d+ (?:1 \d+ )?B \d+ C\d+ ', string):
    reprocess(re.sub(r'^(A \d+ (?:1 \d+ )B \d+ C\d+) (.*)$', r'\2 \1', string))
```

But it seems silly to run the regular expression twice.

I can't just do the `re.sub()` because if the regex doesn't match, it still returns a string result that's just the original unchanged string, and I don't want the reprocessing to happen if it didn't match. I suppose I could compare that against the original string, but that seems silly.

I'd like there to be a way for `re.sub()` to return a false value if it fails to substitute anything.

The best thing that I can come up with is:

```
for string in stringlist:
  (subst, replaced) = re.subn(r'^(A \d+ (?:1 \d+ )B \d+ C\d+) (.*)$', r'\2 \1', string)
  if replaced:
    reprocess(subst)
```

which seems wordy and just sloppy.

Is there not a better, more pythonic way?

Comment: If you have a test inside `reprocess` that causes it to return the input unchanged, you could call `reprocess(re.subn(r'^(A \d+ (?:1 \d+ )B \d+ C\d+) (.*)$', r'\2 \1', string))` and add the `replaced` value of the tuple to that test. Otherwise I think you're stuck with the "silly" string compare or what you have.

Comment: I think the more pythonic way would be to compile the regular expression since it doesn't change, and use a replacement function to to process things when a match is made.

Comment: `re.subn` is the right approach, why do you think it is sloppy?

Comment: @anubhava Part of it is the intermediate `replaced` variable instead of it just being part of the `if` statement. The other, bigger, part is that I'd already asked this question before I found `subn`, and the old way I had suggested really was sloppy.

Comment: @WombatPM Simply compiling the regex doesn't prevent running the same regex twice. Unless python caches previous runs against a compiled regex and can just immediately substitute in a previously calculated result for the same input.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
import re
my_pattern = r'^(A \d+ (?:1 \d+ )B \d+ C\d+) (.*)$'
compiled = re.compile(my_pattern). # This is a re.Pattern object

def replace_function(match_obj):
    a = match_obj.group(1)
    b = match_obj.group(2)
    if a is not None and b is not None:
         return f"{b} {a}"
    else:
         return None


for s in stringlist:
    replaced = compiled.sub(replace_function, s)  # All the same methods are available, with the pattern compiled
    if replaced:
        reprocess(subst)
```

You could even place your reprocessing logic in the function is you desired

Comment: +1 for telling me about the fact that you can pass in a function to do the substitution instead of the normal string-based substitution.

Comment: And you only run the re against a string once, because you pass the matched object into the replace function